# Printing different strings for reading different object variables

Tags: c++, class

I wish to output different string for reading variables. For example, below, I wish to print **Enter english marks** before reading **english marks** using **eng.setmarks()**. Please suggest a way to implement this.

Here is my code: (look at **for** loop below)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;

class student {
    char name[20];
    int age;

    class marks {
        int marks;
        public:
            void setmarks( int x) {
                marks = x;
            }
            int getmarks() {
                return marks;
            }
    };

    public:
        marks eng, math, phy, chem, cs; // nested objects are public

        void setname( char* n) {
            strncpy( name, n, 20);
        }
        char* getname() {
            return name;
        }
        void setage( int a) {
            age = a;
        }
        float total() {
            size_t total = eng.getmarks() + math.getmarks() +
            phy.getmarks() + chem.getmarks() + cs.getmarks();

            return total/500.0;
        }
};

int main() {a
    student new_stud;


    char temp[20];

    cout << "Enter name:  ";
    cin >> temp;
    cin.get( temp, sizeof(temp));
    new_stud.setname(temp);

    int age;

    cout << "Enter age:  ";
    cin >> age;
    new_stud.setage( age);

    for( size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        // I wish to output: "Enter marks in" + subject_name, but harcoding it seems tedious
    }

    cout << "\nTotal Percentage:  " << new_stud.total();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i didn't understand what you are asking? Could you elaborate it more precisely.

Comment: I mean the words wont have to be written, eg when I read different subjects marks, I have to write explicitly to print *"Enter English marks: "* and read the marks. So if no of subjects is large, it becomes a headache. I think **Marci** has given good solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, you would like to print out the name of the variable which you are about to read into. Now this can't be done on the way you want it. The best thing you can do is make an array of subject names, and an array of marks.

```
string[5] Subjects = {"Maths", "English", "Chemistry", "Physiscs", "Computer Sciences"};
marks[5] Marks;
for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
  cout << "Please enter marks in " << Subjects[i] << ":" << endl;
  int a;
  cin >> a;
  Marks[i].setmarks(a);
}
```

You could also make the *marks* class have a field *subject name*, and give it a function *inputfromuser()*, like this:

```
class marks {
  int marks;
  string subjectName;
  public:
  void setmarks( int x) {
    marks = x;
  }
  int getmarks() {
    return marks;
  }
  void inputfromuser() {
    cout << "Please enter marks in " << subjectName << ":" << endl;
    cin >> marks;
  }
};
```

Sorry for me using the *std::string* type, I am not very comfortable with the raw *char[]* way to handle texts.